# Is it wrong to upvote an answer on a question I have downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, low-quality-posts, upvotes

I just downvoted a not-so-good question that just contains one paragraph with a question that is answered by just opening the manual of the specific framework.

However, right after that an answer appeared containing a nice code example answering the question, complete with a link to the correct manual page.

I upvoted the answer as it was not only correct but also from a user with hardly any reputation and a quick check (after upvoting...) even showed it was the users first answer.

So the user definitely deserved the upvote although the question should not be there and my upvote effectively blocks the OP from deleting it.

Should I not have upvoted the answer?

Comment: If anything, a quality answer from someone who was able to see through the ambiguity and general lack of information provided from a poorly written question should *definitely* be up-voted. I've seen a few that demonstrated obvious knowledge and effort well in excess of what was put into the OP's question and I try to reward the act. Many times these replies will also come under the `Tenacious` or `Unsung Hero` badge category so a few up-votes may be the only reward.

Comment: I wonder a little bit about this question from a 50k user. Aren't there enough MSO questions of this kind which you have read during the last 5 years?

Comment: If it's a bad question, I downvote it.  If it's a good answer, I upvote it.  Two independent factors :)

Comment: I like to upvote good answers, but on a bad or ambiguous question it can be difficult to determine if the answer actually answers the question being asked.

Comment: @ThomasW. No, I didn't come here much before and a search didn't give me any results. And as I was just curious I thought I'd ask...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Any post, be it a question or an answer, should be up or down voted on its own merits. From the "Privileges - vote up" page in the help center:

> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

The operative word here is "whenever". Context shouldn't matter: would it be wrong to downvote a bad answer on a good question? Obviously not, and by the same token a bad question deserving of a downvote can result a good answer which should be voted up.

Comment: But note that sometimes people will *downvote* answers (even if they are good ones) to bad questions, because they may be thought to encourage bad questions, or at least don't encourage askers to improve their questions.  The *scope* of "useful" can be interpreted in different ways: "useful to the site as a whole" (encourage better questions, or encourage good answers), "useful to the OP", "useful to others who find it", etc.

Comment: The question is: "Are answers to bad questions ever useful?" My take, if the question has some promise, sure. If it is off-topic, never. And then it gets fuzzy. So I disagree, the important word is **useful**.

Comment: I tend to upvote an answer which contains the information I was looking for, regardless of whether or not the question or answer have run afoul of the site's rules.  A common example is when a question posted on SO should have been posted on SU or SF--especially when the technical matters therein are ... ahem, perhaps too complex for SU or SF.