# Stance on answering "bad" questions

Tags: discussion, answers, bad-questions

Just a few minutes ago, I came across (and flagged as off-topic) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786177/offline-mobile-application-development-with-java), asked by someone who joined just before posting.

The thing is, it got an answer, which made me wonder what the official stance was on this kind of answer on a blatantly "bad" question -- it's easily within the definition of "off-topic".

Another, similar question titled "What do I need to know for trading stocks?" (now closed; [link for the interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547895/what-do-i-need-to-know-for-trading-stocks)) also got a few answers, despite being even more off-topic. I answered it anyway, with a bunch of links to help the asker, since I was then as unclear as I am now on what I should do.

My questions are these:

- If/when I encounter a blatantly off-topic question, should I not post an answer, even if I can?
- If I find an answer on one, should I flag that, or downvote it, or just leave it alone?

It seems harmful to suggest that these kinds of questions are acceptable by allowing answers, but at the same time, those questions could be migrated, answers and all, to whatever site they belong to.

I've already read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267540/dont-answer-bad-questions), but that's about a mildly "bad" question, as opposed to the two I linked above. I've also seen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254565/are-we-encouraging-answers-to-bad-questions), but the answer doesn't cover my question, I think. Then there's [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531), which made me think that it's a bad idea to do so, but there's a higher-voted answer which describes a different solution, which made me think the opposite.

Comment: The answers on the first question you linked to fully address this - if a question is so bad it should be closed, then you should move to close it rather than answer. If a question is sub-par but not garbage, improve it and go ahead and answer. That's a line that's going to take a bit of judgement, but that's as good as it's likely to get.

Comment: @sphanley That doesn't answer my second question, though. What should I do to answers on bad questions?

Comment: Vote on them based on their merit. There's another question which addresses that (which as it happened I answered): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276079/is-it-wrong-to-upvote-an-answer-on-a-question-i-have-downvoted/276081#276081

Comment: @sphanley ...Great. That answer does answer my question perfectly, but the question is only distantly related to mine. Would you mind copy/pasting the answer over so I can accept it? Or is there something else I should do?

Comment: @Will Rude comments? Alright, you... uh, bad person.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ask yourself this: why do we close bad (unclear, overly-broad/opinion-based) questions?

**A:** Because that way they can't be answered.

**Q:** Why don't we want them to be answered?

**A:** Because bad questions tend to attract bad answers.

**Q:** Then what should I do when I see a bad question attracting bad answers?

**A:** Close the question and downvote the bad answers. (And downvote the question too).

**Q:** What if a bad question gets a *good* answer?

**A:** Then don't downvote the answer, obviously. If it's otherwise on-topic, you might be able to edit the question to be less bad - thus preserving a home for the good answer.

**Q:** So what if *I* have a good answer to a bad question?

**A:** Then edit the question to make it not-bad, and post your answer! You can even [earn a badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) for this...

#### See also: [How to decide which questions I should not answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254549/how-to-decide-which-questions-i-should-not-answer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question was more for questions that just couldn't be edited to be fit for the site, but the rest still applies. I suppose I shouldn't answer what I can't edit to fix, then?

Comment: You'd be surprised at what *can* be fixed... Folks who write good answers to bad questions tend to do so by making a lot of educated guesses based on experience with similar problems, and there's no reason not to apply those assumptions to the question itself. But yeah, if **you** don't see a way to fix it, then I would move on to a better question.

Comment: I'll do that. I'd also like to point you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547895/what-do-i-need-to-know-for-trading-stocks) as an example of what I mean by "unfixable", if it still exists.

Comment: I'd wager it's impossible (or prohibitively difficult) to write a good, comprehensive answer to that question as well, @newbiedoodle - which of course is why it was closed/deleted. That, and the fact that it was completely off-topic. Note that there can be *good* questions that are off-topic as well, and they're just as impossible to fix - which is why I didn't really touch on them in this answer.

Comment: That and he fact that it was asked on a site about programming. Anyway, many thanks for the great answer. I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: If the OP didn't google an obvious question. Can I post LMGTFY link without getting downvoted?

Comment: Is a LMGTFY link ever a good answer, @Remian? Imagine you googled your question, and the top result was an answer on Stack Overflow telling you to google the question. Would you find that useful and not a waste of your time?

Comment: @Shog9, Ah I just asked a silly question. What if I just give him the appropriate link

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259 @Remian8985