# How much edit to a question is too much?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently I answered a question with what I feel was a great answer that could help anyone who wanted to make a string with numbers increase sequentially. The question I answered, however, was very broad and poorly worded. The OP said they had code and offered to post it but have since gone silent.

I edited the post (which went to queue) to better fit the scope of what they were asking, in a way that was easier for others to understand and held more keywords for any future searches on the subject. In doing so, I rewrote just about everything the OP wrote, but in what I feel are better words. My edit didn't change the scope of the question. [This is the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360611/vba-code-to-auto-serial-number-in-column-a-after-my-userform-entered-data-in-col). [Here is my rejected edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13605343)

Where did I go wrong? How much is too much? Thanks for your help on this. I had read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions/281795#281795) before I made my answer, and I was trying to turn the question into a good one.

Comment: You should link to the suggested edit, not to a picture of the suggested edit.

Comment: I don't see how that edit changes most of the important problems with that question.  It still seems like a pretty bad question even after the edit.

Comment: It doesn't, but it was a bad question to begin with. I didn't want to change the scope, just make it more clear what they were trying to achieve without wording it as a code-for-me question. I was also trying to avoid modifying the question to fit my answer. I just wanted to edit it in a way that would be easier for others to understand and contribute to.

Comment: "wording it as a code-for-me question." I don't see how that is any less true after your edit.  But yes, it does seem a bit clearer.

Comment: I think you are wasting your time on a clearly off-topic question. Flag to close and move on to something that is more worthy of your time and energy.

Comment: Also, be aware that by posting a link to the original question, you may end up inviting a flood of downvotes via the [Meta Effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235226/191410)

Comment: If I saw that edit come up, I would really struggle with how you, who are not the OP, managed to nearly double the length of the question. I'd probably open the question in a new tab and see that there wasn't much in the way of comments on the question that would lead to the additional text. That makes it seem like you're putting words into the OP's mouth, which is the rejection reason.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I totally see where you're coming from, and in a lot of ways I agree. And what you say too, JDB. (The Meta Effect on this question wouldn't really be misplaced). I just wanted clarification from seasoned SE-ers on where I went wrong so as to not waste my time in the future. The answer was too simple, and the question too poorly asked for me to have spent any time on it. Thanks for your input and advice!